# Using RQuantLib in Java with RJava

Tags: options, black-scholes, r, programming, rquantlib

Can't seem to get an answer to this on stackoverflow. I'm relatively new to using RJava and was getting a null pointer exception from a piece of code I was trying out. I suspect that this could be due to the data type I am using, but am a bit confused about how to solve this. Any help with this would be great.

```
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;

public class RJava {

public static void main(String a[]) {


    String javaVector = "c(put, 0.0425, 66.592, 66.00, 0, 0.068, 0.072, 0.1)";


    Rengine engine = new Rengine(new String[] { "--no-save" }, false, null);


    engine.eval("library(RQuantLib)");
    engine.eval("rVector=" + javaVector);
    engine.eval("Euvol=EuropeanOptionImpliedVolatility(rVector)");

    double vol = engine.eval("Euvol").asDouble();
    System.out.println("Vol=" + vol);

}
 }

   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at co.karan.RJava.main(RJava.java:49)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should at least give the line number where your code crashes (49 is **not** the line number you show in the question).

You have a null exception and it happens in `RJava`, have you tried to use a debugger to figure out where exactly it crashes?

Your code can't crash in `javaVector` and `new Rengine` because the Java runtime guarantees it'll throw an exception but it won't be a null exception. Your code  also can't crash in your `eval` calls. So what else?

Your code crashes in `engine.eval("Euvol")`. The function `eval` gives you a null and you try to cast to double, you can't do this.

Now, you should think why your R engine gave you a null exception. There're several possibilities:

**1**: You don't have QuantLib installed. RQuantLib won't work if your QuantLib is not properly installed. Worse, you might not even have RQuantLib installed.

**2**: Your inputs to RQuanlib are not correct. Read the documentation:

[image]

The first argument is a **STRING**. In your code you gave `put`, this is a **variable** but not a string.

The R vector `c(put, 0.0425, 66.592, 66.00, 0, 0.068, 0.072, 0.1)` is invalid. Try to copy it to your R and you'll get an error.